# Rails Devise Omniauth new_user_registration_url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, omniauth

I had implemented devise gem and omniauth-facebook before few months into my app and everything was worked as usual, until now when I deleted my fb user from db.
Now I am trying to sign in again as nonexisting user and all the time I am redirected to Devise Sign Up form.

So I cant log in/ register my FB user into my app.

What can cause this type of problem?

routes.rb

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
```

omniouth_callback_controller.rb

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def facebook
    # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end

  def failure
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

user.rb model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]

  def self.new_with_session(params, session)
    super.tap do |user|
      if data = session["devise.facebook_data"] && session["devise.facebook_data"]["extra"]["raw_info"]
        user.email = data["email"] if user.email.blank?
      end
    end
  end


  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
      user.name = auth.info.name   # assuming the user model has a name
      user.image = auth.info.image # assuming the user model has an image
    end
  end
```

rails routes

```
     new_user_session GET      /users/sign_in(.:format)                 devise/sessions#new
                    user_session POST     /users/sign_in(.:format)                 devise/sessions#create
            destroy_user_session DELETE   /users/sign_out(.:format)                devise/sessions#destroy
user_facebook_omniauth_authorize GET|POST /users/auth/facebook(.:format)           users/omniauth_callbacks#passthru
 user_facebook_omniauth_callback GET|POST /users/auth/facebook/callback(.:format)  users/omniauth_callbacks#facebook
               new_user_password GET      /users/password/new(.:format)            devise/passwords#new
              edit_user_password GET      /users/password/edit(.:format)           devise/passwords#edit
                   user_password PATCH    /users/password(.:format)                devise/passwords#update
                                 PUT      /users/password(.:format)                devise/passwords#update
                                 POST     /users/password(.:format)                devise/passwords#create
        cancel_user_registration GET      /users/cancel(.:format)                  devise/registrations#cancel
           new_user_registration GET      /users/sign_up(.:format)                 devise/registrations#new
          edit_user_registration GET      /users/edit(.:format)                    devise/registrations#edit
               user_registration PATCH    /users(.:format)                         devise/registrations#update
                                 PUT      /users(.:format)                         devise/registrations#update
                                 DELETE   /users(.:format)                         devise/registrations#destroy
                                 POST     /users(.:format)                         devise/registrations#create
```

Comment: Thank you for a try but that's not fix,  tried nothing and didnt do any change there, the code is there the same for few months also in tutorial there are no user.save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason in user.rb  model I had one association belongs_to:somemodel and that I was put there for testing some model relations.

So commenting this line I am logged in by facebook!